# how to link jquery code to jsp code to display form?

Tags: jquery, jsp

```js
$(function(){

 // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#loginform").validate({
    
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: 
        {
            uid: "required",
            password:
            {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            confirmpassword:
            {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
      role: "required",
        },
        
        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: 
        {
         uid: "Please enter your user ID",
            password: 
            {
       required: "Please provide a password",
       minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 character",
            },
            confirmpassword: 
             {
        required: "Please provide a password",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 character",
        equalTo: "your password should be same as above"
             },
            role: "Please specify your role",
        },
         onClick: function(loginform) 
         {
          loginform.submit();
            }

      });

  });
```

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 
<%@ include file="include.jsp" %>

<!--  <div id="body"> -->
<%--     This is page 1. Rendering time: <%=new java.util.Date()%> --%> 
<!--  </div-->
<html>
<!-- <head> -->
<!--  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> -->
<!-- </head> -->
<body>
 <div>

<form method="post" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="page1.jsp">
  <table cellpadding="5" border="0">
  <h3> Add a new user </h3>
   <tr>
    <td align="center">User ID:</td>
    <td><input tabindex="2" size="60" type="text" name="uid" id="uid"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center">Password:</td>
    <td><input tabindex="2" size="60" type="password" name="password" id="password"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center">Confirm Password:</td>
    <td><input tabindex="2" size="60" type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
   <td align="center">Role:</td>
   <td><select name="role"> 
   <option value="">Select a specific role to be alloted to the user</option>
    <option value="OPS(Operational)">OPS(Operational)</option>
    <option value="Helpdesk">Helpdesk</option>
   </select></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input tabindex="5" type="button" value="Submit" onClick="validate();"/></td>     
   </tr>
   
  </table>    
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i have this jsp page to display the form. i have included jquery library in other jsp file. but  this jquery code is not working. i m unable to have client side validations on the browser. and also submit button code is not working. plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

To submit your from you can try this

```
function validate() {
        var flag = false;
        flag = $("#loginForm").valid();

        if (flag) {
            document.loginForm.action = "page1.jsp";
            document.loginForm.submit();
        }
    }
```

here .valid() is by default provided by jquery.validat.js which returns true or false

Edited:
this is simplest demo i tried

index.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ include file="include.jsp" %>

<!--    <div id="body"> -->
<%--     This is page 1. Rendering time: <%=new java.util.Date()%> --%> 
<!--    </div-->
<html>
<!-- <head> -->
<!--    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> -->
<!-- </head> -->
<body>
 <div>
<form role="form" id="form">
                                    <div class="form-group"><label>Password</label> <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password"></div>
                                    <div class="form-group"><label>Url</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" class="form-control" name="url"></div>
                                    <div class="form-group"><label>Number</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" class="form-control" name="number"></div>
                                    <div class="form-group"><label>MinLength</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" class="form-control" name="min"></div>
                                    <div class="form-group"><label>MaxLength</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" class="form-control" name="max"></div>
                                    <div>
                                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-t-n-xs" type="submit"><strong>Submit</strong></button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

include.jsp

```
 <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#form").validate({
          rules: {
              password: {
                  required: true,
                  minlength: 3
              },
              url: {
                  required: true,
                  url: true
              },
              number: {
                  required: true,
                  number: true
              },
              min: {
                  required: true,
                  minlength: 6
              },
              max: {
                  required: true,
                  maxlength: 4
              }
          }
      });
 });
</script>
  </script>
```

Comment: Have you included jquery.js file in your included file.make sure your jquery is running .

Comment: Yes sir. I have included that in include.jsp .

Comment: should i post include.jsp file ?

Comment: change uid: "required" with  uid: {required: true}